# PHP multidimensional array to individual arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that allows multiple values for inputs

**Car One**

```
<input type="text" name="vehicle[]" placeholder="Enter Your Vehicle" />
```

**Car Two**

```
<input type="text" name="vehicle[]" placeholder="Enter Your Vehicle" />
```

When submitted it translates to an array like so

```
["vehicle"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Acura"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Mazda"
 }

["doors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "4 Door"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "2 Door"
  }
```

I want to then translate this to individual arrays that are like so

```
[VehicleOne]=>
  array(1) {
    [vehicle]=>
    string(5) "Acura"
    [doors]=>
    string(5) "4 door"
  }
```

I have a custom function I created that does this but I am wondering if there are native php methods that can be used instead of multiple loops?

So this is what I am currently using. Not every $_POST value is an array so I have to check and if is then I divide them up.

```
foreach ($fields as $key => $row) {

   if(is_array($row)){

     foreach ($row as $column => $value) {

        $doctors[$column][$key] = $value;

     }

  }

}
```

Comment: You should include your "multiple loops" in your question.

Comment: Lol, no I just had to work on other stuff. You can check my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need, just construct the array the way you want it in the inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="data[0][vehicle]" placeholder="Enter Your Vehicle" />
<input type="text" name="data[1][vehicle]" placeholder="Enter Your Vehicle" />
<input type="text" name="data[0][doors]"   placeholder="Enter Your Doors" />
<input type="text" name="data[1][doors]"   placeholder="Enter Your Doors" />
```

Then `$_POST` will contain:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [vehicle] => Acura
                    [doors] => 4 door
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [vehicle] => Maza
                    [doors] => 2 door
                )
        )
)
```

If you can't/won't change the form, then something like:

```
foreach($_POST['vehicle'] as $k => $v) {
    $result[] = ['vehicle' => $v, 'doors' => $_POST['doors'][$k]];
}
```

Will yield:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [vehicle] => Acura
            [doors] => 4 door
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [vehicle] => Maza
            [doors] => 2 door
        )
)
```

Using something like `VehicleOne` etc. is pointless when using arrays as you are only doing this to make it unique, when 0, 1, etc. already is.

Comment: unfortunately the main form is cloned via jquery, so each vehicle is just added via the same form that is cloned. Its hard to explain but basically I can't modify the html because if I do the change will occur to all cloned forms.

Comment: Edited with a loop.

Comment: OP wants associative array of I understand the question correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can work for you?
I create a temporary array with associative keys that I later extract to multiple arrays ($vehicle1 and 2).

```
Foreach($vehicle["vehicle"] as $key => $v){
    $temp["vehicle" . ($key+1)]["vehicle"] = $v;
    $temp["vehicle" . ($key+1)]["doors"] = $d["doors"][$key];
}
Extract($temp);
Var_dump($vehicle1, $vehicle2);
```

It's one loop, not multiple loops at least.

https://3v4l.org/ltoEs